# Deploying and Installing Sharepoint apps into App catalog using CSOM

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

Can anyone suggest me on how to use SP.AppCatalog() in JSOM or CSOM and get the all apps in AppCatalog, Not AppInstances..

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to install the apps via the Sharepoint UI?

Comment: Stephen- Idea is.. I want to deploy all apps at a time into the app catalog, so I thought CSOM with Powershell cmdlets is a good idea..

Answer (score 2):

Not verified. But the AppCatalog is a SharePoint Library, i think you just have to add the *.app files to this list for deployment. there are plenty examaples of how to add a file to a library. Rest of the internal installation processing is automatically done by eventreceivers or workflows, i guess.

Installing might eventually be the bigger problem, atm i am not aware of a function which do this, but i think there should be one.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint CSOM API exposes the following methods:

- [Web.LoadAndInstallApp method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.loadandinstallapp(v=office.15).aspx) - Uploads and installs an app package to this site
- [Web.LoadAndInstallAppInSpecifiedLocale method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.loadandinstallappinspecifiedlocale(v=office.15).aspx) - Uploads and
  installs an App package, in a specified locale
- [Web.LoadApp method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.loadapp(v=office.15).aspx) - Uploads an App package and creates an
  instance from it

### How to deploy (upload & install) SharePoint App via CSOM

```
/// <summary>
/// Deploy SP App 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">Client context</param>
/// <param name="appFullPath">Full path to app file (.app)</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static AppInstance DeployApp(ClientContext context, string appFullPath)
{
    using (var packageStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(appFullPath))
    {
       var appInstance = context.Web.LoadAndInstallApp(packageStream);
       context.Load(appInstance);
       context.ExecuteQuery();
       return appInstance;
    }
 }
```

Usage

The following example demonstrates how to deploy SP App into SharePoint Online

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{              
      ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
      var appInstance = DeployApp(ctx, @"C:\Packages\SPApp.app");
      if (appInstance != null && appInstance.Status == AppInstanceStatus.Initialized)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("App was installed.");
      }
 }
```

Retrieve App instances

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
    ctx.Credentials = CreateSPOCredentials(userName, password);

    var appInstances = AppCatalog.GetAppInstances(ctx, ctx.Web);
    ctx.Load(appInstances);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (var appInstance in appInstances)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(appInstance.Title);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apps can't be installed using CSOM or JSOM. Powershell is good choice.

Some links:

- [Install and uninstall SharePoint apps using powershell script](http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/98/Install-and-uninstall-SharePoint-apps-using-power-shell-script)
- [Add apps for SharePoint to a SharePoint 2013 site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161231(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: That's not correct. -- Check out the `Web.LoadAndInstallApp` methods. -- https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/How-to-install-add-inapp-to-SharePoint-sites-using-CSOM

Answer (score 1):

@kosikovec i doubt it is possible through powershell if you are looking at sharepoint online.There are no powershell scripts for app deployment to sharpeoint online