# CSOM: Add app to web that is present in organization app catalog

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom

I need to install Apps to a web programmatically using CSOM. Apps are already added to the App Catalog of the tenancy. Is it possible?

I am aware of [LoadAndInstallApp API and it works](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159456/sponline-install-and-trust-an-app-using-csom/164307#164307) but requires some features to be enabled on site that I don't want to. I feel it is cleaner if App is installed from App Catalog directly. We have faced issues with LoadAndInstallApp when we do it on site collection and also on sub sites as it gives error that App is already present. Thanks.

Comment: have you found any solution approach?

Comment: Sorry, didn't find any solution for this. We had to introduce a manual step in our setup to install Apps just because of this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You still have a PS approach via Install-SPApp, however, will you then have server-side coding dependencies.